# Message is not allocated to specific thread when running multiple thread JMeter websocket plugin

Tags: jmeter

I run the JMeter websocket with 10 threads and use While Controller to read message by using WebSocket Single Read Sampler. However, my expected data for thread 10 has been read in thread 9 so my loop cannot end. How can I sort this issue out?

My Test Plan
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE9VU.png

My issue
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFwUX.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot suggest anything meaningful without knowing how the "messages" are being handled by the backend, blind shot: your [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)  or parameterization fails somewhere somehow and multiple threads are connecting to the same session so the server responds to "wrong" thread as it is not able to distinguish the connections.

Double check all outgoing message details using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/), it might also be a good idea to enable debug logging for WebSocket Samplers plugin by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

and upon JMeter restart you will see many more details in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Comment: The system uses signalr and all the connection in one pc uses the same session so it leads to my issue.